# My dedicated TF2 server will not connect to Steam servers. (Error = 8)

Tags: steam, team-fortress-2, hosting, server-administration

I am trying to set up a dedicated TF2 server on one of my computers and I cannot figure out what the issue is.

I am using Linux (Debian 11) and the computer is wired to my router.

Upon starting the server, I get an error saying:
"Server is hibernating
Could not establish connection to Steam servers.  (Result = 8)"

Ports 27000 - 27040 are forwarded.

Here is the full log when I boot up the server:

```
    tf2-server@tf2:~/hlserver/tf2$ ./tf2.sh
WARNING: No map specified! Server may not heartbeat.
Auto detecting CPU
Using default binary: ./srcds_linux
Server will auto-restart if there is a crash.
Using Breakpad minidump system. Version: 7961495 AppID: 232250
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 232250
Using breakpad crash handler
Loaded 10791 VPK file hashes from /home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/tf/tf2_textures.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 10791 VPK file hashes from /home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/tf/tf2_textures.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 478 VPK file hashes from /home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/tf/tf2_sound_vo_english.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 478 VPK file hashes from /home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/tf/tf2_sound_vo_english.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 1343 VPK file hashes from /home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/tf/tf2_sound_misc.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 1343 VPK file hashes from /home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/tf/tf2_sound_misc.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 2795 VPK file hashes from /home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/tf/tf2_misc.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 2795 VPK file hashes from /home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/tf/tf2_misc.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 2795 VPK file hashes from /home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/tf/tf2_misc.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 1232 VPK file hashes from /home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/hl2/hl2_textures.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 574 VPK file hashes from /home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/hl2/hl2_sound_vo_english.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 383 VPK file hashes from /home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/hl2/hl2_sound_misc.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 450 VPK file hashes from /home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/hl2/hl2_misc.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 450 VPK file hashes from /home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/hl2/hl2_misc.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 5 VPK file hashes from /home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/platform/platform_misc.vpk for pure server operation.
Loaded 5 VPK file hashes from /home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/platform/platform_misc.vpk for pure server operation.
server_srv.so loaded for "Team Fortress"
For FCVAR_REPLICATED, ConVar must be defined in client and game .dlls (sv_use_steam_voice)
ProtoDefs post data loaded.
ProtoDefs loaded. 19.13 MB used
ProtoDefs post data loaded.
ProtoDefs loaded. 19.13 MB used
maxplayers set to 24
No '-replayserverdir' parameter found - using default replay folder.
Replay: Creating thread pool...succeeded.
Replay: Starting thread pool with 4 threads...succeeded.
Cleaning files from temp dir, "/home/tf2-server/hlserver/tf2/tf/replay/server/tmp/" ...no files removed.
ProtoDefs post data loaded.
ProtoDefs post data loaded.
dlopen failed trying to load:
/home/tf2-server/.steam/sdk32/steamclient.so
with error:
/home/tf2-server/.steam/sdk32/steamclient.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit
Unknown command "r_decal_cullsize"
#--------------------------------------------------------
sv_pure set to 1.
#--------------------------------------------------------
Using map cycle file 'cfg/mapcycle_default.txt'.  ('cfg/mapcycle.txt' was not found.)
randommap: selecting map 20 out of 48
ConVarRef dev_loadtime_map_start doesn't point to an existing ConVar
maxplayers set to 24
Unknown command "startupmenu"
Network: IP 127.0.1.1, mode MP, dedicated Yes, ports 27015 SV / 27005 CL
Initializing Steam libraries for secure Internet server
[S_API] SteamAPI_Init(): Loaded local 'steamclient.so' OK.
CAppInfoCacheReadFromDiskThread took 1 milliseconds to initialize
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 440
dlopen failed trying to load:
/home/tf2-server/.steam/sdk32/steamclient.so
with error:
/home/tf2-server/.steam/sdk32/steamclient.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Looking up breakpad interfaces from steamclient
Calling BreakpadMiniDumpSystemInit
[S_API FAIL] Tried to access Steam interface SteamUtils010 before SteamAPI_Init succeeded.
Setting breakpad minidump AppID = 232250
Logging into Steam game server account
pure_server_whitelist.txt not present; pure server using only base file rules
trusted_keys.txt not present; pure server using only base trusted key list
ConVarRef room_type doesn't point to an existing ConVar
Executing dedicated server config file server.cfg
VSCRIPT: Started VScript virtual machine using script language 'Squirrel'
VSCRIPT: Started VScript virtual machine using script language 'Squirrel'
Script not found (scripts/vscripts/mapspawn.nut) 
Script not found (scripts/vscripts/mapspawn.nut) 
Set motd from file 'motd.txt'.  ('cfg/motd.txt' was not found.)
Set motd_text from file 'cfg/motd_text_default.txt'.  ('cfg/motd_text.txt' was not found.)
SV_ActivateServer: setting tickrate to 66.7
'koth_viaduct.cfg' not present; not executing.
Server is hibernating
Could not establish connection to Steam servers.  (Result = 8)
```

Answer (score 3):

The server output suggests that the server is not binding to the correct IP address or interface.

Your output has:

```
Network: IP 127.0.1.1, mode MP, dedicated Yes, ports 27015 SV / 27005 CL
```

Which indicates it's working from the `lo` interface or similar, i.e. localhost only.

Try adding `+ip 0.0.0.0` to your startup command to listen and bind on all IPv4 addresses, or specify a specific address to bind to in case of a multihome setup.

An example startup command is `./srcds_run -game tf -console -port 27015 +map itemtest +ip 0.0.0.0 -strictportbind`

If it is still not reachable, try to bind to a specific address, such as the server's LAN address, and see if raises an error in trying to do so. If it cannot bind to the server's address you expect it to, there may be other issues in the network configuration. In this case, more information would be required, such as if the server is running in docker, is in a jail/chroot, interface priorities are wrong, or apparmor is interfering.